# show modal pop up on radiobutton click

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

```
<tr>
    <td align="left">Have you asked the employee to leave without serving the notice period</td>
    <td align="left">
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoBtnleaveWoNoticeyes" runat="server" GroupName="Replacement" 
             Text="Yes" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" AutoPostBack="true" 
             oncheckedchanged="rdoBtnleaveWoNoticeyes_CheckedChanged" /> &nbsp;
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoBtnleaveWoNoticeno" runat="server" GroupName="Replacement" 
             Text="No" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small"  AutoPostBack="true"
             oncheckedchanged="rdoBtnleaveWoNoticeno_CheckedChanged" />
    </td>
    <td align="left" colspan="2"><%--Remark--%>
    </td>
</tr>
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="cc18_ModalPopupExtender" 
     runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" TargetControlID="rdoBtnleaveWoNoticeyes" PopupControlID="Panel18" CancelControlID="btnwonoticeperiod">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel18" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none;top:50px">
    <table width="90%" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;font-family: Arial; font-size: small" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
        <tr><td align="left">
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_leaveWoNotice" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td align="center">
            <asp:Button ID="btnwonoticeperiod" runat="server"  Text="Save" OnClick="btnPLAdjSave_Click" CssClass="clsButtonpopup" />&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="clsButtonpopup" />
        </td></tr>
    </table>
</asp:Panel>
```

I want to show modal popup on radiobtn checked above is the design. Below is code. iam not getting output kindly suggesat wat is to be done

```
protected void rdoBtnleaveWoNoticeyes_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rdoBtnleaveWoNoticeyes.Checked == true)
    {
        lbl_leaveWoNotice.Text = "As you have asked the employee to leave without serving notice, there will be no Notice recovery from employee and employee will receive his PL encashment treating this as “Ask to leave” case.";
        trNoticePayRecovery.Visible = true;
        cc18_ModalPopupExtender.TargetControlID = "rdoBtnleaveWoNoticeyes";
        cc18_ModalPopupExtender.Show();
    }
}

protected void rdoBtnleaveWoNoticeno_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl_leaveWoNotice.Text = "As process there will be Notice period shortfall recovery with PL bal adjustment from employee.";               
    trNoticePayRecovery.Visible = false;
    cc18_ModalPopupExtender.TargetControlID = "rdoBtnleaveWoNoticeno";
    cc18_ModalPopupExtender.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting desired output as you are going to assign TargetControlID after the event getting fired.
Just remove the lines:

```
cc18_ModalPopupExtender.TargetControlID = "rdoBtnleaveWoNoticeno";


cc18_ModalPopupExtender.TargetControlID = "rdoBtnleaveWoNoticeyes";
```

May be it will help you.